# Pass argument to java annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I'm combining multiple annotations into a single custom annotation.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Annotation1(input = SomeClass.class)
@Annotation2(input = SomeClass.class)
@Annotation3(input = SomeClass.class)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```

can I take SomeClass.class as input parameter from CustomAnnotation and make it generic?
So I can use it somewhere like below

```
@CustomAnnotation(input=SomeClass.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

> can I take SomeClass.class as input parameter from CustomAnnotation and make it generic?

Yes, you can. Here's an [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) of the `@Import` annotation from the `Spring` framework.

**You use it like this ...**

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(other.namespace.Foo.class) // class name specified here
class SpringBootImportTest {
```

And its [implemented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.java) like this ...

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Import {

    /**
     * {@link Configuration @Configuration}, {@link ImportSelector},
     * {@link ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar}, or regular component classes to import.
     */
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

For more details about creating custom annotation check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-annotations-in-java).

Comment: taking input is fine, but how can I use this input to provide it in annotation used inside `CustomAnnotation`?

Comment: You need to write an annotation processor that will use it https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder